# Using linq to query two sorted lists

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am pulling in a hotfix list with wmi into a sortedlist.  I then have the cluster fixes in another list built from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545685

```
Dim p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes As New sortedList
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2525380") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2446607") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2531907") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2550886") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2552040") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2520235") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2494162") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2524478") = ""
p_Windows2008R2sp1ClusterFixes("2494162") = ""

Dim hotfixArray As String() = {981391, 981392, 977236, 981111, 977238, 977239 }
For i As Integer = 0 To hotfixArray.Length - 1
          slMissingList(hotfixArray(i)) = hotfixArray(i)
Next
```

I want to be able to do an inner join to see what fixes are installed and a left outer join using linq to tell me what fixes are not installed. 
there are several hundred fixes on 1 to 16 machines.  I need to be able to see what fixes are each machine.

Comment: You could use Hashsets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908036(v=vs.90).aspx).  They make set differencing and intersection easy.

Comment: HashSets are great if you only care about the key. A Dictionary would probably be a better fit than a SortedList if you need both and don't really care if they are kept sorted or not.  You could always use a SortedDictionary but I'm guess that it would be acceptable to sort as needed and the O(1) lookup characteristics of the HashSet or Dictionary are more important when performing the difference. Of course, it could be that the data sets are small enough that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will give your approach a try as I really do not need it to be sorted only remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for can be done with `Where`.  It's hard to tell from your question which list contains what but it would look something like:

```
   Dim available As New SortedList(Of string,string)
   Dim installed As New SortedList(Of string,string)

   Dim availableInstalled = available.Where( Function(a) installed.ContainsKey(a.Key))
   Dim missing = available.Where( Function(a) Not installed.ContainsKey(a.Key))
```

Comment: @BobDutton looks like you're new to Stack Overflow. Generally when an answer solves your problem, you mark it as the Accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to the vote buttons.  Once you have enough rep you can also up vote helpful answers, regardless of whether you accept them or not.  You might want to take a tour through the help section to become more familiar with how it works, http://stackoverflow.com/help